# Sitecore Forward Search generates wrong URLs

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm using Sitecore Forward Search. Currently I've added a replace into web.config file to replace spaces in item names from one character to another. And now, in  item URLs, spaces are replaced by one character and forward search still generates links with another character. How to fix this problem? I've tried to re-index Search index, but it still the same. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend going back to a standard hyphen rather than an em dash.  Em dash is a non-standard character.  Very few users would even realize the difference between that and a hyphen and even if they did, they wouldn't know how to type it.

Disclaimer aside, if your links are being generated properly when you browse the site, your search engine should be picking them up.  Did you just run the indexer or did you do a "Clean re-index"?  If it is still not getting the correct URLs after a clean re-index, I would double (or triple) check your configs and then contact Forward Search support.

Comment: and what is clean re-index? I just click on Run the indexer for this index button in ForwardSearchAdministartion client.

Comment: Right next to the gear icon that you clicked with the tooltip "Run the indexer for this index", there should be an icon that looks like a recycle symbol that with the tooltip "Run the clean reindex for this index"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this module I created: [SEO-friendly URL module](https://github.com/ParTech/Seo-Friendly-Url)

It implements a custom `LinkProvider` and `ItemResolver` that replaces special characters in your URL, one of them being spaces replaced for hyphens (-).

The thing you're doing now is simply replacing spaces for hyphens, but Sitecore is then not able to resolve the items anymore.

Comment: Aside from whats listed in "Usage" (which is very useful), how is SEO module different from setting `lowercaseUrls="true"` and [replacing spaces in url with a dash](http://sitecoreninja.blogspot.ca/2013/03/replace-space-with-dash-in-url.html) in standard SC web.config?

Comment: If you replace spaces with a dash using standard config and you have items that already have a dash in the name by default, you will run into problems when you try to resolve those items. E.g. 'item name-test' would be replaced to 'item-name-test' in your URL. If you request that URL, it will be replaced to 'item name test' and it won't resolve to the item 'item name-test' anymore.

Comment: Ahhh yes, I'm aware of that, usually just disallow that in item names or replace at creation time. Thanks, good to know though.

Comment: And the lowerCaseUrls attribute didn't exist before 6.4.1 rev 120113. The module has actually been in use for quite a while ;-)

Comment: Lol, everyone has their own little toolbox :)

Answer (score 0):

Ben is right, a "clean reindex" might do the trick, but it depends on version.

Manual approach:

1. Delete Index folder(location might depend on configuration)
2. Delete Storage subfolder(location defaultly as subfolder to ForwardData)
3. Trigger a full update(Trigger tool or admin client)

At this point Forward Search should index the site in the context of a normal visitor and links should be resolved as such.

Sometimes there are certain navigation elements as breadcrumbs which by mistake generate other/duplicate links; like links with "Sitecore/content" as prefix or a language specification.
This can be circumvented by using canonical or adjusting the exclude pattern.

Best regards
Thomas Jensen, Part of the Forward Search team